# Geometric proof that the tetrahedral group is a subgroup of the icosahedral group

Tags: group-theory

An exercise in Artin's *Algebra* asks to determine all subgroups of the icosahedral group. If one knows that

1. the tetrahedral group $T$ is isomorphic to $A_4$
2. the icosahedral group $I$ is isomorphic to $A_5$

then it is obvious that $T$ is a subgroup of $I$. Now the argument for why fact 2 is true is not presented until the next chapter, so perhaps Artin intended for there to be some way to solve this problem without using that fact. On the other hand, I suppose fact 1, which is easier to prove, can be used.

Is there a proof that $T$ is a subgroup of $I$ that doesn't use fact 2, and only uses the geometric structure of $I$?

I suppose we could say that $T$ is the stabilizer of one of the five cubes inscribed in the dodecahedron, but this doesn't seem easy to prove geometrically either.

Comment: The 20 vertices of the dodecahedron can be partitioned into five tetrahedra; 'by inspection' this would seem to pretty cleanly give the result?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I don't see how you can do that. Could you post a diagram showing one of the tetrahedra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three vertices marked here plus the antipodal vertex to the center one in this figure form a tetrahedron:

[image]

(The rotation of $2\pi/3$ about the axis orthogonal to the screen through the center of this figure obviously maps these three points onto themselves and leaves the antipodal vertex invariant, and a little fooling with a physical dodecahedron should make it clear that the antipodal vertex is in identical position with respect to all three visible vertices as they are to each other.)

Comment: Here's another nice image http://www.gregegan.net/SCIENCE/Origami/tetdod.png